# Python: How to use decimals instead of rounding?

Tags: python, decimal, calculator

Ok, I know how to normally use decimals with mathematical calculations in Python. But these use variables. So I do not know how to do it in my instance. This is a calculator I typed up real quick but I do not know how to use decimals. Thanks a lot!!

```
def addition(a, b):
    return a + b

def subtraction(a, b):
    return a - b

def multiplication(a, b):
    return a * b

def division(a, b):
    return a / b

print """\nThis is a calculator. You can add, subtract, multiply, or divide with a max of two variables."""

print """\nTo add: Type 1
\nTo subtract: Type 2
\nTo multiply: Type 3
\nTo divide: Type 4 """

sign = raw_input("\n\nPlease enter a number  >")


if sign == "1":
    first = int(raw_input("\n\nEnter your first number to add  >"))
    second = int(raw_input("\n\nEnter your second number to add  >"))
    print "\nYour result is:\n"
    print addition(first, second)


elif sign == "2":
    first = int(raw_input("\n\nEnter your first number to subract  >"))
    second = int(raw_input("\n\nEnter your second number to subract  >"))
    print "\nYour result is:\n"
    print subtraction(first, second)

elif sign == "3":
    first = int(raw_input("\n\nEnter your first number to multiply  >"))
    second =int(raw_input("\n\nEnter your second number to multiply  >"))
    print "\nYour result is:\n"
    print multiplication(first, second)

elif sign == "4":
    first = int(raw_input("\n\nEnter your first number to divide  >"))
    second =int(raw_input("\n\nEnter your second number to divide  >"))
    print "\nYour result is:\n"
    print division(first, second)
```

Comment: I think you're looking for https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Comment: You are casting everything to `int`.  Perhaps you want to cast to `float` or `decimal.Decimal` instead.

Comment: Well, [there _is_ a tutorial in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#quick-start-tutorial). You should use that to learn to _"know how to use decimals"_. Also, if you want do use decimals, why are you casting to int?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `int(...)` use either `float(...)` or `decimal.Decimal(...)`.

Example:

```
import decimal
d = decimal.Decimal(raw_input("\nEnter a number >"))
print(d)
```

or:

```
f = float(raw_input("\nEnter a number >"))
print(f)
```

Comment: Thank you! I am going to do this!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind losing precision use floating point variables.

If you want to keep precision, I'd suggest using this:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

.. rather than rolling your own decimal maths library.